# Entrada de contraseñas con python

Tags: python

Hola: queria saber como ingresar por teclado una palabra, pero que al ir ingresandola me aparezca por pantalla astericos. (como si fuera una contraseña)

Comment: Bienvenida! He cambiado el título de tu pregunta para que refleje mejor tu consulta. "Funciones en python" hacía pensar en otra cosa.

Answer (score 5):

Si lo que quieres es que la contraseña no sea visible mientras se teclea, la biblioteca estándar tiene un módulo para ello:

```
import getpass
p = getpass.getpass("Contraseña: ")
```

Si lo que quieres es que vayan apareciendo asteriscos conforme se teclea, la solución es más complicada, pues necesitas un método para detectar la pulsación de la tecla en el momento en que se produce, lo que implica acceder a características específicas de la terminal, que dependen del operativo. No se hace de la misma forma en Windows que en Linux, por ejemplo. Y aún cuando tengas eso resuelto, está el problema de que deberías permitir al usuario "corregir" lo escrito, es decir, detectar la tecla de borrado para eliminar parte de lo escrito y sustituirlo por otra cosa.

No conozco bibliotecas que hagan específicamente esto, pero existe una biblioteca muy chula llamada [bullet](https://github.com/Mckinsey666/bullet) que permite muchos tipos de entrada avanzada de datos por terminal (menús, listas desplegables, checkboxes,...) y entre ellos justamente lo que quieres. La siguiente imagen es de su documentación:

[image: Ejemplo]

Y se consigue por ejemplo así:

```
from bullet import Password

cli = Password("Contraseña: ")
p= cli.launch()
```

Comment: buena info, pero  lo hago  en sublime text .

Comment: Sublime text es el editor. No veo qué tiene que ver aquí. A menos que te refieras a que _también lo ejecutas_ desde sublime text. En ese caso no lo estás ejecutando en una terminal real, sino en la emulación que haga sublime. En mi experiencia ninguno de los emuladores de terminal integrados en un editor permiten ocultar la contraseña mientras se teclea. Ni siquiera usando el estándar `getpass`.