# Cómo hacer casting de un string o int en Python?

Tags: python

Hay alguna posibilidad de convertir por ejemplo un string o un int a `*` (un asterisco) en Python?. Como si fuera el inicio de sesión de una pag web

```py
usuario2 = input("\tIngrese su usuario: ")
contraseña2 = int(input("\tIngrese su contraseña: "))
```

Comment: Lo más parecido es el módulo `getpass`  que oculta completamente el input, eso te podría servir?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no es exactamente lo que buscaba pero me sirve. Gracias por la ayuda!!!!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Entrada de contraseñas con python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254338/entrada-de-contrase%c3%b1as-con-python)